# I want a shared folder between Arch (host) and Android

Tags: linux, arch-linux, android, large-files, music

I have a music folder of nearly 10 GB, of completely offline music. I want to keep it on my phone, so i can take it on the go. The simplest answer is a file transfer between my phone and PC, however it wont stay up to date with the new addition and removal of music on my PC.

my best idea is figuring out how to use VSFTPD and getting a client on my phone and keeping it in sync on my phone, but I think there could be a simpler way.

Thank you! dropbox and google drive are out of the question because of the size. Google Drive is already full, anyway.

Comment: If size is the problem Mega.nz offers 50GB for free. But the Android client doesn't synchronize, it downloads/uploads on demand. However, Dropbox or Google Drive Android clients do the same. You can't automatically synchronize a FTP server in the phone either (and it would require many additional configurations in order to be accessible from outside you home network and, depending on your ISP, it may not be possible at all).

Comment: @Cosmo Write a script on the PC to do these in order: 1) delete removed files from Android then 2) copy new files on PC to Android. Sub-steps: 1A) Make list on PC of music files on Android 1B) Make list on PC of music files on PC 1C) Compare lists, output a list of music files on Android but not on PC 1D) Delete files on Android in the list '1C'. 2A) When was sync last done? Look at timetamp of file 'LAST'. 2B) Make list music files new on PC since 'Last'. 2C) Copy those files to Android. 2C) Use _touch_ to update timestamp of file 'LAST'.